# What differences are there in funerary practices between madhhabs?

Tags: fiqh, madhhab, funeral

I am not Muslim; just writing a paper.

I understand that there are eight schools of jurisprudence according to the Amman Message of 2004 (disregarding the doubts I've seen some people express about its wording). My essay is on the impacts that these madhhabs, in conjunction with local cultures, have on the Muslim funeral. However, all the sources I've found tend to treat funeral customs as a monolith.

I'd really appreciate if anyone could direct me to sources that detail the differences in how Muslims following different schools of thought might practice death rites-- if there's any at all.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. What exactly are you looking for rites after a person has died or from the moment his/her death seems close and until  when (burying ...?)? Please note that local customs are not on-topic.